# JDBI how can I delete data from two tables in one @SqlUpdate

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

I have two tables:

```
entities:
- id
- someValues
```

and other table, with foregin key on id field

```
connectedEntities:
- entityId (foregin)
- otherObjectId (foregin)
```

I need to delete entity by id, but when I tried to delete just from `entities` table, there's FK violation.

Also, I want to use @SqlUpdate or other annotation from JDBI framework.

Does anybody know how to do something like this?

Comment: In your database schema, have the foreign keys been set to cascade the delete? Because dropping something from `entities` if it's referenced in `connectedEntities` should cascade to that table if that's how the foreign key was specified.

Comment: Check this: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: It seems you set foreign key with on delete no action property in this case first you need to delete entries from child table then you can from master...further to check please show output of "show create table table_name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @G_H , I found what I was looking for.

I just needed to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to my foregin key definition, and everything worked just fine.

Here's the tutorial - [mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade](http://mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade)